# Two-way Summary Table in Julia (with weight by third variable)

Tags: julia

Has anyone implemented a two-way frequency(summary) table in Julia? I'm looking to create summary tables (means, sums, etc.) in Julia, with the option to weight continuous variables by a third variable (very important). Essentially, I want the abilities of proc tabulate/means, for those familiar with SAS.

I searched around and found this was discussed at one point but does not appear to have moved anywhere since. I'm at the point where I will look to code this up myself, but I want to see what the communities thoughts are before proceeding.

Comment: This question is not a good fit for StackOverflow as you don't actually have a problem here. I would suggest posting it instead to the [julia-users group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/julia-users).

Comment: Showing an example, even in SAS, might help to spark some ideas/interest.